# Arbitrage when discounting and forward computation is done with different curves

Tags: derivatives, forward, discounting

I notice that (equity derivatives) trades generally are priced with different forward curve and discounting curve, which clearly lead to arbitrage. Is this arbitrage value too small to be ignored? How is it managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last edition (10th, 2017) of Hull's book explains it fairly well. Basically, there is indeed a theoretical arbitrage within the dual curve framework: you could borrow at the overnight rate (Fed funds, SONIA, EONIA, etc.), lend at LIBOR and cash-in the spread in all your dynamic derivatives replication trades. However, such arbitrage is only theoretical : try to do that in practice!

As a matter of fact, the OIS discounting is relevant for collateralised derivatives since the derivative's value is funded by the collateral that is typically funded at the overnight rate. LIBOR is only useful as a benchmark to determine the derivative's payoff, and also (but there is still debate here) for non collateralised transactions since in such case, the derivative's mark-to-market is funded by the winning counterparty.

Comment: Thanks @siou0107! Do you remember which chapter of the hull book has this information?

Comment: The one on HJM model, there is a part on "Multiple zero curves"

Comment: Thank you very much!